# Need to add two values in perl

Tags: perl

In if condition I used to take one value from log file after matching the particular pattern. That pattern is matched two times in log file. While matching the pattern first time that value is 0 and second time value is 48. It may be also reverse. First value may contain 48 and second value may contain 0. I need to calculate the exact value. So I planned to add these two values. but after adding these two values also while printing the total value in if condition I used to get the two values separately. But I need single value only.

Please give me solution to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Your description is mostly just confusing. For example "may contain 48"? What does that mean? Does it mean that the number can be "1048"? Example code and input/output would be much more useful.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this:

```
my $entry = "First is 10, seconds is 48";
if(my ($a,$b) = $entry =~ /(\d+)/g) {
    print $a + $b,"\n";     # 58
}
```

But without actual code it is hard to see what your problem really is.